# Will I get answers to all my questions when I die?

Tags: nature-of-god, history, heaven, comparative-christianity

Sorry if this is way too open but I have so many questions about this world, religion, gods and what on earth is going on. I can't imagine anyone really would be able to answer these type of questions now but will I find out at the end? I've probably watched and read too many conspiracy theories about stuff like this and dug myself into a hole but I just get sucked in and want to know. Will I ever find out?

Also while I was thinking about what to ask on here and put myself out there, hoping not to come across as a moron, why did I start to get a little upset?? Is it wrong to ask these things?

I won't go on and see what I get back from this.

Comment: Yeah I guessed as much. Wasn't sure if this was the right place to ask but stumbled upon it when I was googling other questions. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack, Luke.  We're a bit different to other question and answer sites so please take our tour to find out what sort of questions work here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Suggestion: How about asking Where can I get Christian answers to all my questions about God and the afterlife?  You need to specify if you want answers from Catholics, Protestants or a specific denomination. That should eliminate the philosophical aspect and invite people to give a Christian answer.  Perhaps other users can help you here?

Comment: There is little point in finding out how to live one's life when one has no life left to live.

Comment: Ha, looks like lots of people really wanted to answer your question (more than vote to close it) but it's pretty far afield for the subject of this website.  If you want an overview of christian thought on the matter, please ask for that - just tagging "comparative-christiantiy" isn't enough.  Needless to say, I think you've already got a lot answers that might help you.

Comment: @Luke Christianity, Judaism, and possibly Hinduism are **the most open to questions** among the world religions as they welcome questions which undermine every imaginable aspect of the religion.  Doesn't mean it can answer every question, but you will not be reprimanded for asking it.  To reopen this question, though, you need to be more specific in narrowing the **1)** type of questions (see [my preliminary answer for ideas](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/78935/10672)) and **2)** denomination (if in doubt, I recommend Catholicism as the most generous for this type of inquiry)

Comment: Wow! Cheers for all the feedback guys. Wasn't expecting this much input but really appreciate it all. I think I need to get myself a Bible and do some research. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Before Jesus began preaching in Israel, there came a 'man sent from God' whose name was John. John the Baptist, we know him as.

When the people asked John what should they do, he gave very specific insructions.

- 1. If anyone is lacking in food or clothing, and we have more than we need, we are to give it to them.
- 2. Those who collect taxes for Government are only to collect what they are authorised to collect. They are not to over charge.
- 3. Soldiers who are paid to keep order in the nation are to do only that, without resorting to inappropriate brutality.
- 4. John also rebuked the King (Herod) for his inappropriate conduct regarding marriage. Marriage is important to the order of society and is not to be tampered with.

Some, receiving these instructions, desired more and those he baptised with water and they confessed their sins.

This is the background, immediately before Jesus 'came preaching'.

There is nothing difficult or grievous or mysterious about any of this.

You can see it in the bible, in Matthew, Mark and Luke. John is different, but John shows the spiritual reasons for it.

This is how we are to live . . . .

. . . .  until the day we die.

---

There is much, much more to learn, regarding Christianity.

*But this is how we begin.*

---

Answer (score 1):

The biblical perspective is that we need to get our questions asked and answered before we die.  That’s because our eternal destination depends on what we do now, in this life.

> “Just as man is destined to die once, and after that to face judgment, so Christ was sacrificed once to take away the sins of many people; and he will appear a second time, not to bear sin, but to bring salvation to those who are waiting for him” (Hebrews 9:27-28).

Life’s biggest questions are answered in the Bible:

• Does God exist, and, if so, what is He like?

• Who am I?

• Why am I here?

• What is my purpose in life?

• Why is there so much pain and suffering in the world?

• How can I live a joyful, meaningful life in a world with so much evil?

• What happens after I die?

• Is history headed somewhere?

The Bible has lots to say about these important issues.  https://www.gotquestions.org/lifes-biggest-questions.html

The way things are going right now, lots of people are anxious and scared about the future.  It’s never wrong to ask questions.  Indeed, there is no such thing as a stupid question – only stupid answers.  From a Protestant point of view, I recommend you get the answers from the Bible.  Hope this helps to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: **probably**.  There are:

- questions Christianity can answer *right now* with confidence
- questions Christianity *promises* we will know after we die
- questions God *may* answer after we die
- questions on what will happen in the *future*
- questions that God *may* answer an *individual* (private questions such as why one's child dies)

### Christian epistemology

In Christianity, a lot depends on **what God decides to reveal to us**.  These are either truths about Him or aspects of the world that *cannot be measured by science*, which are what this answer will focus on.  These are questions that only Philosophy and Religion can answer, such as:

- the *immeasureable* aspects of the world: the *why* questions, how God sustains the world, etc.
- non *physical* human questions: meaning of life, what a true human flourishing looks like, etc.
- the existence, role, and purpose of immaterial beings (angels, demons, spirits, rulers, principalities, etc.) and how they affect us
- the nature of God and what God wants of us

Christianity teaches that we have to rely on God for those truths because although reason may have some inkling to those truths (because God endows reason with his image) **only God can know them infallibly**. Secondly, Christianity teaches **a God that we can trust NOT to deceive us**, out of His Goodness.  In other words, the Christian God is a God who wants us to flourish with His Truth, Goodness, Beauty, Love, Grace, etc.  Christians can then be confident Christianity will NOT be just another myth or fantasy or speculation or even conspiracy theory.  Our trust in God makes us able to rely on those truths to take risk in making difficult decisions in our life, such as sacrificing creature comfort for a good cause, or even giving our life to save our spouse / child in times of danger.  We have examples of Christian martyrs and saints who trust God in this way.

Christianity teaches that **God reveals those truths in several ways** (different denominations have different mix and priorities):

1. Through the measurable world that our 5 senses can perceive plus the aid of our scientific instruments
2. Through the light of reason that are embedded in every human being
3. Through the light of faith that God gives to us in our soul
4. Through God's own incarnation as a human being in Jesus Christ
5. Through His prophets and apostles whose writings are recorded in the Bible
6. Through the teachings of faith/community/church leaders that are led by the God, including those who designate certain writings/creeds/ confessions as sacred/trustworthy
7. Through the private revelations to those gifted by God such as contemporary prophets or saints

### Examples

**Questions Christianity can answer *right now* with confidence**

**Questions Christianity *promises* we will know after we die**

**Questions God *may* answer after we die**

**Questions on what will happen in the *future***

**Questions that God *may* answer an *individual***

(to be continued)

Comment: The transcendence of God means there will be some questions we'll never get full answers to, like how things are from God's experience.

Comment: @curiousdannii Agreed.  Even in heaven God will probably still be transcendent to us, even though we will be able to see at least the God-man Jesus.  Even if the most generous understanding of the Beatific Vision turns out to be true, I don't think it implies that God will answer all our questions.  I love how C.S. Lewis deals with this in "The Magician's Nephew" ([Ch 12, 6th paragraph](https://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/lewiscs-magiciansnephew/lewiscs-magiciansnephew-00-h.html#chap12)) how Aslan didn't answer Digory but showed "big, bright tears" which would have satisfied Digory's grief.

Answer (score 1):

The Apostle Paul said:

> 9 For we know in part and we prophesy in part, 10 but when
> completeness comes, what is in part disappears. 11 When I was a child,
> I talked like a child, I thought like a child, I reasoned like a
> child. When I became a man, I put the ways of childhood behind me. 12
> For now we see only a reflection as in a mirror; then we shall see
> face to face. Now I know in part; then I shall know fully, even as I
> am fully known. (1 Corinthians 13:9-12)

We will all know more (at least believers). We will remain finite beings, so we will never know everything, for it is impossible for finite beings to hold infinite knowledge.

The words of a hymn may answer this better:

```
Turn your eyes upon Jesus,
Look full in His wonderful face,
And the things of earth will grow strangely dim,
  In the light of His glory and grace.
```

The things you now want answers to may become trifling things once the fulness of God enters your view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding Answers about #Time in Heaven:

- "When will this happen?"

We learn in Matthew 24:36 - "But about that day or hour no one knows, not even the angels in heaven, nor the Son, but only the Father."

2. Regarding #Questions we want Answered in Heaven:

We learn from Iyov (Job) 37:20 - "Need it be told to Him when I speak, or need a man tell what is kept a secret?" (הַֽיְסֻפַּר־ל֖וֹ כִּ֣י אֲדַבֵּ֑ר אִם־אָ֥מַר אִ֜֗ישׁ כִּ֣י יְבֻלָּֽע )

3. Regarding #Answers God gives us in Life:

- What is my Soul's purpose in Life?

We learn from Devarim (Deuteronomy) 6:5 - "And you shall love the Lord, your God, with all your heart and with all your soul, and with all your means." (וְאָ֣הַבְתָּ֔ אֵ֖ת יְהֹוָ֣ה אֱלֹהֶ֑יךָ בְּכָל־לְבָֽבְךָ֥ וּבְכָל־נַפְשְׁךָ֖ וּבְכָל־מְאֹדֶֽךָ)

We learn from Vayikra (Leviticus) 19:18 - "you shall love your neighbor as yourself." (וְאָֽהַבְתָּ֥ לְרֵֽעֲךָ֖ כָּמ֑וֹךָ )

We learn from our Salvation in God the Answer that matters in life [Mark 12:28-31] - "28 Of all the commandments, which is the most important?” 29 “The most important one,” answered Jesus, “is this: ‘Hear, O Israel: The Lord our God, the Lord is one. 30 Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind and with all your strength.’ 31 The second is this: ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’ * There is no commandment greater than these.”

4. When we focus on loving God and our Neighbor, all questions will be answered in Life.

שַׁבָּת שָׁלוֹם